# Add URl to the article in the bibliography

Tags: citing

I did not find a journal for the paper I have cited from. Therefor I want to add an URL of the article entry in the bibliography. I have already added it but I am getting for this note `(accessed on Nov. 6th, 2015}` in the article entry  without space between the words.

Is it possible to add some spaces between the words in the note? Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

**tex code**

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    english,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{a4}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksopen=true,
            bookmarksnumbered=true,
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=black,
            linkcolor=black                 
            ]
            {hyperref}

\begin{document}

Mowing down trees, flooding streets and battering buildings, Patricia hit land as a Category 5 hurricane on Friday \cite{recordingData2} evening before grinding inland. It moved quickly but lost power in the mountains that rise up along the Pacific coast and was downgraded to a tropical depression on Saturday morning as it \cite{waze} headed through central Mexico \cite{recordingData}.

        \bibliographystyle{plainurl}
        \bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

**bibliography.bib**

```
@article{recordingData2,
  author = {Leon Stenneth and Ouri Wolfson and Philip S. Yu and Bo Xu},
  title = {Transportation Mode Detection using Mobile Phones and GIS Information},
journal = {ACM DL},
  year = {2011},
    pages = {3}
}

     @misc{waze,
         author = {androidcommunity.com},
         title = {Waze traffic app updates with Foursquare and Yelp integration},
         howpublished = {\url{http://androidcommunity.com/waze-traffic-app-updates-with-foursquare-and-yelp-integration-20120131/}},
  note = {Accessed: 29.09.2015}
}

@article{recordingData,
  author = {Rudolf Giffinger},
  title = {Smart cities Ranking of European medium-sized cities},
  journal = {Report of Centre of Regional Science},
  year = {October 2007},
  url  = {http://www.smart-cities.eu/download/smart_cities_final_report.pdf (accessed on Nov. 6th, 2015},
  pages = {11}
}
```

Comment: The options for document class or packages use  […], not  \[…\].

Comment: @Bernard: Sorry but I did not understand your comment. Where Have I to use it?

Comment: You have, say, `\usepackage\[T1\]{fontenc}` instead of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, and a  lot of such syntax errors.

Comment: @Bernard: Also in my original file I have them as your correction I do not how these errors appear in the syntax. But this does not solve the problem.

Comment: @TheBook The backslashes appeared because you hit the wrong button before the `{}` one. Never mind. I'd simply use a `note` field with the URL and the accession date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your bib entries:

- Do keep the information that belongs to `year` and `month` fields separate.
- Likewise, don't amalgamate the contents of `url` and `note` fields.
- Don't neglect to encase words that shouldn't be lower-cased -- such as "European", "GIS", "Yelp", and "Foursquare" -- in curly braces.
- Do load the `url` package explicitly, and specify the option `hyphens` when loading the package so that long url strings can be line-broken at dash characters.

A separate matter: I think the entry `recordingData` contains several additional errors. First, you probably shouldn't use the entry type `@article`, as the publication does not appear to satisfy the usual criteria for a journal article. Do look into whether the `@techreport` entry type is more suitable. Second, the report has quite a few authors, not just Rudolf Giffinger. What are you trying to achieve by omitting the names of five of the six authors? Third, what is the field `pages = {11}` about? According to the link you provide, the report contains 28 pages rather than 11.

Giving off the impression of being cavalier or, worse, careless about the correctness of the entries in bibliography section is *not* a good way to engender a reader's trust in the correctness of the remainder of your paper or report.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{recordingData2,
  author = {Leon Stenneth and Ouri Wolfson and Philip S. Yu and Bo Xu},
  title = {Transportation Mode Detection using Mobile Phones and {GIS} Information},
  journal = {ACM DL},
  year = {2011},
  pages = {3},
} 
@misc{waze,
   author = {androidcommunity.com},
   title = {Waze traffic app updates with {Foursquare} and {Yelp} integration},
   howpublished = {\url{http://androidcommunity.com/waze-traffic-app-updates-with-foursquare-and-yelp-integration-20120131/}},
   note = {Accessed: 29.09.2015}
}
@article{recordingData,
  author = {Rudolf Giffinger},
  title = {Smart cities Ranking of {European} medium-sized cities},
  journal = {Report of Centre of Regional Science},
  year = 2007,
  month = "October",
  url  = {http://www.smart-cities.eu/download/smart_cities_final_report.pdf},
  note = "Accessed: Nov.~6, 2015",
  pages = {11}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
    11pt,english,twoside,a4paper,headsepline,footsepline
    ]{scrbook}

%%\usepackage{a4}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
           bookmarksnumbered=true,
           colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black                 
           ]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

        \nocite{*}
        \bibliographystyle{plainurl}
        \bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to keep the citation in the document successive? I have used before "\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}" but I could not display the url in the article entry. Therefor I changed the style to  `\bibliographystyle{plainurl}` but it does not keep the order of  citation through the pages. Currently I am getting 3,1,2 and I want the order to be 1,2,3

Comment: @TheBook - Not sure I understand the term "successive". Are you asking how to go about have the ordering of the entries in the bibliography be the same as their citation order? If so, you may want to give the `unsrtnat` bibliography style a try; if you go this route, don't load the `cite` citation management package, and do load the `natbib` citation management package. The `ieeetr` style, by the way, is well more than 20 years old by now; as it dates to an era from before the Internet (and having bib resources online), it's not surprising that it doesn't know what to do with URLs.